# Spring Boot basic Cacheing is Not working for me

Tags: java, spring-mvc, caching, spring-boot

I am trying to do a simple cache of data but everytime I test it. It never seems to cache the data.

## package app;

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheManager;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        return new ConcurrentMapCacheManager("getUserInfo");
    }

}
```

## package app.cache;

```
import app.repo.User.User;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;


@Service
public class UserService {

    private User userInfo;

    @CacheEvict("getUserInfo")
    public void setUserInfo(User userInfo) {
        this.userInfo = userInfo;
    }

    @Cacheable("getUserInfo")
    public User getUserInfo() {
        return userInfo;
    }
}
```

## package app.controllers;

```
import app.cache.UserService;
import app.repo.User.Player;
import app.repo.User.User;
import app.repo.User.UserRepo;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;

@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userCache;


    @RequestMapping("/test-user-cache")
    @ResponseBody
    public User testUserCache() {
        if(userCache.getUserInfo() != null) {
            return userCache.getUserInfo();
        }
        User user = new User("joejoe","wordpass");
        user.setId(44444444);
        userCache.setUserInfo(user);
        return userCache.getUserInfo();
    }

}
```

## Dependencies

```
...
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
            <artifactId>apacheds-server-jndi</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
...
```

It doesnt seem to save the data when I try to save it. And when I do a request again, no data is never cached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get that behavior **because** the cache works. The data is saved, but `null` is already cached: `if(userCache.getUserInfo()`

In order to clear the cache when you set the value you can annotate the `setUserInfo` Method with `@CacheEvict(cacheNames="books", allEntries=true)`.

Comment: Well how do I get it where I can update the cache on demand. I tried adding `CachePut` but still no luck. I updated more code. And why isn't the set method working. It skips over `getUserInfo()` because like you stated, its already null, but it does set the value and nothing is saved.

Comment: You have to clear the cache by annotating `setUserInfo` with `@CacheEvict`. `@CachePut` would indeed put something in the cache, but `setUserInfo` has no parameter, so it would be useless.

Comment: Your definitely on to something. But its still not working. I added `CacheEvict` to the `setUserInfo` and still nothing. It still returns null when I try to do the `getUserInfo`. On the other hand when I do set the values before doing the first `getUserInfo()` method. It returns a value.

Comment: You were close. I couldnt add the CacheEvict to the setUserInfo. Instead I had to create a seperate method called Clear and call it before I set the value again. If there is a way I can CacheEvict before I set the value instead of after. I would appreciate the tip.

Comment: In anycase, update your answer to include that I must call CacheEvict first and I will mark it as correct.

Comment: It should work. `setUserInfo` has to be annotated with `@CacheEvict(cacheNames="books", allEntries=true)`.